# C#: Windows Form creating table and and retrieve data from database by each dynamic button click

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

1. I am trying  to develop a restaurant billing application in windows form.
2. so I created dynamic buttons.
3. now I need a table which will retrieve data from database for each button click.

How can it possible?

```
 private void newb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Button btn = (Button)sender;
     //  textBox1.Text = btn.Text;
     connection con = new connection();
     con.connecting();
     // Button b = new Button();
     int i = 0;
     var query = "select itemname,itemcode,price from item_master                     where itemcode =" + btn.Name;
     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con.con);
     while (i < 10)
     {

         MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
         DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
         sda.Fill(dbdataset);
         BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
         bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;

         dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
      //  MessageBox.Show(btn.Name);
         i++;
     }
    // sda.Update(dbdataset);
 //  =dataGridView1.Rows[0]

//// MySqlDataReader mdr;
//// mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// while (mdr.Read()) 
// {
////  textBox1.Text = (mdr["itemname"].ToString());
// }
}

 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }

 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {

 }
```